# RemoteWebDriver throws "org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'am trying to run a simple code from hub to node, hub and node connections are successful.

While executing the program I am getting the exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException
```

Chrome driver path which I have mentioned is a share path that can be accessible from the node machine.

- Chrome Version: 58.0.3029.110
- Chrome Driver Version: 2.9

Both Hub and Node are remote machines.

**Below is the code used:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Q:\\xxxxx\\chromedriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    dc.setBrowserName("chrome");
    dc.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.xx.xxx.xx:5566/wd/hub"), dc); //node url
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

}
```

**Below is the console message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, platform=VISTA}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'A5DAFC-W7A-0012', ip: '10.xx.xxx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at testcases.Grid.main(Grid.java:23)
```

Comment: The error `SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=chrome, platform=VISTA}]`  says it all. Can you share the commands you used to start the Hub & Node? Thanks

Comment: Sure thanks for the reply. Hub command: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -port 4123 Node Command: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://10.xx.xxx.xx:4123/grid/register -port 5566

Comment: The `System.setProperty()` call is superfluous when connecting to a hub using the `RemoteWebDriver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As you have used the following command to start the **Selenium Grid Hub**:

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -port 4123
```

To execute your code block through `chromedriver.exe` and `Google Chrome` Browser you can consider to start the **Selenium Grid Node** on port **5566** through this command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4123/grid/register -port 5566
```

Access the Selenium Grid Hub Console through **`<IP_of_GridHub>:4123/grid/console`** to see the Node being registered.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to environment variables, set system variable as `"JAVA_HOME" C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301`, this will rectify this issue.